# Localized timezone names

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I'm converting user-supplied timestamps into tz-aware `datetime.datetime` instances. The timezone information in the timestamps comes in many formats. One of these are "local" timezone names, such as "MEZ" ("Mitteleuropäische Zeit", German for "Central European Time"). While `pytz` has the corresponding timezone (CET), it is not aware of its localized (i.e. German) name.

Is there a (ideally official and complete) database with localized timezone names that I can use to map local timezone names to official names?

Comment: http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/dates.html#localized-time-zone-names

Comment: @deceze: If I understand the documentation correct, then Babel provides the other way: given a timezone instance, get its localized name. I have a localized name ("MEZ") and need a timezone instance (CET).

Comment: Ah, that wasn't entirely clear. That seems potentially problematic if you're trying to support *all* timezones in *all* languages, since the abbreviation for timezones may conflict between different languages, unless you can also be sure about what locale is used… You only want to do that for German?

Comment: @deceze: I had not thought about potential conflicts, that is an important point. Currently I only need German, but I'd prefer a solution that works for any locale. I would be fine with having the locale as a parameter, though, e.g. `get_tz_from_localized_name('MEZ', 'de_DE')`.

Comment: even for the english abbreviations, you can run into trouble, e.g. there are [three different BST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)

Comment: @MrFuppes Ah yes, the *BS* Timezones… 